# Can Piwik Be Installed on IIS and SQL Server?

Tags: .net, iis, matomo

I am putting together a recommendation for a web analytics tracking solution for an internal intranet application without a fully qualified domain (i.e. Google Analytics is not an option). It is an ASP.NET application. My research seems to keep pointing me toward Piwik, but I can't tell if there is a way to install it that is fully based in the .Net ecosystem.  What I mean is that I need a tool that can be installed on our server (no recording of data to the cloud), and use C#/.Net, IIS and SQL Server.  There's no Apache, PHP or MySQL here, and it won't be added for this.  When considering the below links, it seems maybe there is a completely MS-based way of handling this, but I'm wondering if anyone knows for sure, or could even explain how they implemented this.

[Piwik C# API Announced](http://piwik.org/blog/2013/02/c-sharp-tracking-and-analytics-api/)
[Piwik Windows Web App Announced](http://piwik.org/blog/2010/08/piwik-on-web-app-gallery/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piwik needs PHP.

Maybe you could hack the SQL to work with MSSQL, but there is no such thing for PHP.

You can install PHP with IIS though (even if with caveats).

EDIT:

The "C# API" is only for data connection and not for actual deployment of the platform.

Comment: Right, so, the idea would be to install PHP on IIS and give it a MySQL instance to talk to, then install Piwik on that box and use the C# API to talk to it from within our code, yeah?  I'll make this suggestion but I doubt they'll approve PHP being installed.  Sad there's no true .Net analytics framework.